# Given $r\gt 0$, how to get $\mu_r = E[|U|^r]$ where $U\sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, expected-value

Given a standard normal random variable $U$ , is there a general formula to compute the expected value of the absolute value of $U$ to any power?

For example given a non negative constant $r$ (i.e $r\gt 0$) how to get $\mu_r = E[|U|^r]$ where $U\sim N(0,1)$?

Comment: I've edited your title to be summarize what your question is about, since finding the "expectation of a standard normal random variable" is not what you're asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a matter of integration:
\begin{align*}
& E[|U|^r] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |u|^r\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}du \\
=& 2\int_0^\infty u^r\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}du \\
=& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty 2^{r/2}t^{r/2}e^{-t}\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{2}t^{-1/2}dt  \tag{set $u = \sqrt{2t}$} \\
=& \frac{2^{r/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{r + 1}{2} - 1}e^{-t}dt \\
=& \frac{2^{r/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{r + 1}{2}\right).
\end{align*}

In the last step, we use the definition of [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Mathematia code: ```
Clear["Global`*"];
distribution = NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]];
meanAbsXPowerR = Mean[TransformedDistribution[(Abs[u])^r, u \[Distributed] distribution]] // FullSimplify
% /. {\[Mu] -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 1}
``` $$
\frac{2^{r/2} \sigma ^r \Gamma \left(\frac{r+1}{2}\right) \, _1F_1\left(-\frac{r}{2};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{\mu ^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}
\\
\frac{2^{r/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{r+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}
$$ The result is consistent with @Zhanxiong's answer (using integral). Where $_1F_1(-\frac{r}{2};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{\mu ^2}{2 \sigma ^2})$ means ` Hype