# Conjecture: $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathbb{E} |X-X'|^p}{\mathbb{E} |X|^p}\leq1.$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable that is nonzero (that is, not identically zero). For any positive real number $p$ such that $\mathbb{E} |X|^p<\infty,$ define
\begin{eqnarray} 
  I_p(X)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathbb{E} |X-X'|^p}{\mathbb{E} |X|^p},    \\
  \end{eqnarray}
where $X'$ is an independent copy of $X$ and $\mathbb{E}$ denotes mathematical expectation. Is the following conjecture true?
$$ Conjecture: I_p(X)\leq1.$$.

This is true for p=1 and p=2, because $I_1$ is the Gini index and $I_2=var(X)/E(X^2)$.
Anyone has a counterexample?

Comment: It is natural and automatic to consider standard Normal variates because then $X-X^\prime$ is a zero-mean Normal variable with variance $2.$ That *immediately,* and with no calculation, gives counterexamples for all $p\gt 2.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conjecture is false.  Here is a counterexample based on $X, X' \text{ i.i.d. } \sim N(0, 1)$.

According to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630468/given-r-gt-0-how-to-get-mu-r-eur-where-u-sim-n0-1/630469#630469),
\begin{align*}
E\left[|X|^3\right] = \frac{2^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
Since $(X - X')/\sqrt{2} \sim N(0, 1)$, applying the same formula to $(X - X')/\sqrt{2}$ yields
\begin{align*}
E\left[|X - X'|^3\right] = \frac{2^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \times 2^{3/2} = \frac{2^3}{\sqrt{\pi}}. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}

$\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$ together imply
\begin{align*}
\frac{E\left[|X - X'|^3\right]}{2E\left[|X|^3\right]} = \frac{2^3}{2 \times 2^{3/2}} = \sqrt{2} > 1,
\end{align*}
which is opposite to the inequality you conjectured.

For another discrete counterexample, let $X, X'$ be i.i.d copies from the binary distribution $P(X = 1) = P(X = -1) = 0.5$, then it is easy to verify that $E\left[|X - X'|^3\right] = 4$ while $E\left[|X|^3\right] = 1$, hence the conjecture inequality fails to hold.

In general, for random variables that are symmetric about $0$, i.e., $P(X \leq 0) = P(X > 0)$, we have $X - X' \overset{d}{=} 2X$ (verify it by calculating their characteristic functions, say), whence for $p > 1$,
\begin{align*}
E\left[|X - X'|^p\right] = 2^pE[|X|^p] > 2 E[|X|^p], 
\end{align*}
so there are actually countless counterexamples.

---

If you know [$c_r$-inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102727/classic-c-r-inequality-in-l-r-space-exyr-leq-c-rexreyr), a possible upper bound of the quotient of your interest can be
\begin{align*}
\frac{c_p(E[|X|^p] + E[|X'|^p])}{2E[|X|^p]} = c_p = \begin{cases}
1 & 0 < p \leq 1, \\
2^{p - 1} & p > 1. 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: You should accept the answer by clicking on the tick symbol alongside the post @seven.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks Zhanxiong!